# How to start AWS EC2 instance automatically using crontab?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

I am trying to start EC2 instance automatically using crontab, but it doesn't work properly.

My crontab setting is like this.

```
0 1 * * * aws ec2 stop-instances  --region=ap-northeast-1 --instance-ids=i-*******
0 8 * * * aws ec2 start-instances  --region=ap-northeast-1 --instance-ids=i-*******
```

In this setting, 'ec2 stop-instances' works perfectly, but 'ec2 start-instances' don't.
It's very weird for me.
If both start and stop feature don't work, I could be convinced.

is there anyone who know what the problem is?
Thank you for your cooperation.

P.S.

If I run 'aws ec2 start-instances' manually, the message what I get is down below.

```
{
    "StartingInstances": [
        {
            "InstanceId": "i-**********", 
            "CurrentState": {
                "Code": 16, 
                "Name": "running"
            }, 
            "PreviousState": {
                "Code": 16, 
                "Name": "running"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

'aws ec2 stop-instances'

```
{
    "StoppingInstances": [
        {
            "InstanceId": "i-024a225909929750a", 
            "CurrentState": {
                "Code": 64, 
                "Name": "stopping"
            }, 
            "PreviousState": {
                "Code": 16, 
                "Name": "running"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Did you check cron logs for any error messages?

Comment: What happens when you run it manually?

Comment: You could manually send the output of the job to a log file and check for errors, eg `0 1 * * * aws ec2 stop-instances  --region=ap-northeast-1 --instance-ids=i-******* >>/tmp/stop-log`

Comment: @Marcin Thank you for your comment, Marcin. I could not see any error messages about 'aws ec2 start-instances' in log file. However, I can see some log about 'aws ec2 stop-instances' which works perfectly like this. ```(ec2-user) CMD (aws ec2 stop-instances  --region=ap-northeast-1 --instance-ids=i-********)```

Comment: @kenlukas Thank you for your comment, kenlukas. I added more infomation about what if I run 'aws ec2 start-instances' manually. Please check it. I hope you are going to find out some problems about this issue.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thank you for your comment. Even though I try to leave some log when 'aws ec2 start-instances' works, I could not see any log in the log file. Therefore, I assume that cron does not make 'aws ec2 start-instances' work.

Comment: If the `stop-instances` command is running, then `aws` is correctly installed and accessible. Either cron isn't running the command, or an error is occurring. I again suggest that you redirect output to a log file because _something_ would appear there.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this question by myself. When I change `aws ec2 start-instances` to `/Users/UserName/.local/bin/aws ec2 start-instances`, it works as I expected.